# Insert a component into another parent component and pass data

Tags: angular, mat-table

Is it possible to insert a component into another parent component and pass data to the child component from the parent component?

1. User Component
2. Table Component
3. Detail Component

in user.html

```
<app-table>
  <app-detail></app-detail>
</app-table>
```

in table.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-content [item]="item"></ng-content> (its my problem)
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify? Do you want to pas data between siblings, or other way? What the expected structure? Where is User component in this structure?

Comment: What is the best way to solve this case?

Comment: Are you asking about `@Input`?. In your question you put `<content [item]="item">` I supouse you want to say `<detail [item]="item"></detail>`

Comment: Go through this article https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/ you will get everything you want

Comment: @Eliseo
Look at the picture. There are three components in the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngTemplateOutlet`:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

```
<app-user>
  <app-table [cardTemplate]="pCard"></app-detail>
</app-user>

<ng-template let-record #pCard>
    <div class="card">

    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Table component:

```
<div class="nsCard">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cardTemplate; context:{$implicit: record}"></ng-container>
</div>
```

And inside table component:

```
@Input() cardTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Actually it is more advanced form of `ng-template`, that provides ability to pass data and many others.